# -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent), useless warning

Tags: c++, c, gcc-warning

When I compile my library I have switched on `-fPIC` because I want to be able to compile it as a shared and as a static library.

Using gcc 3.4.4 on cygwin I get this warning on all source files:

```
-fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent)
```

And I really wonder what's the point of it. It tells me that I use a switch which has no effect because what the switch should achieve is already accomplished. Well, it means it's redundant, fine. But what's the point of it and how can I suppress it?

I'm not talking about why using PIC or not, just why it generates that IMO useless warning.

Comment: So, what's your question really? Don't use  `-fPIC` on that target.

Comment: As I understand the question is "what's the point of it and how can I suppress it?"

Comment: I reported the existence of this warning as a bug on the GCC bug tracker, but the developer seems to think it's OK. The warning is worse than useless--it complicates my Makefile for no reason.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker, thanks! I was wondering if I overlooked something obvious. :) Well, it doesn't cause any problems for me, it's just annyoing because I usually strive to have warning free code.

Comment: I think you should switch to -fpic to remove the warning. -fPIC only makes a difference on some more uncommon platforms

Comment: @Rolle, thanks! I didn't even know there are those differences and applied -fpic now after reading http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2006-09/msg00018.html. The warning is stil there though.

Comment: Consider using [libtool](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/).  It'll set `-fPIC` for you, if supported, if you convey that you *prefer* PIC (`--with-pic`).  See the manual http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libtool.html

Comment: Just a note, using -fpic indeed removed the warning for me.

Comment: This warning is worse than useless. I regularly compile using `-Werror`, and this throws a spurious warning on some platforms.

Comment: So far the best way seems to be `libtool` (possibly driven by `automake`), which uses the right flags depending on the specific action.

Comment: Upgrade to a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Current version (october 2014) is 4.9.1 !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And I really wonder what's the point of it...
>  I'm not talking about why using PIC or not, just why it generates that IMO useless warning.

That's a good question, and I have not seen a definitive answer. At least one of the GCC devs considers it a pointless warning. Paolo Bonzini called it that in his recent patch [Remove pointless -fPIC warning on Windows platforms](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2015-08/msg00836.html).

According to Jonathan Wakely on the GCC mailing list at [How to suppress "warning: -fPIC ignored for target..." under Cygwin](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2015-08/msg00091.html) (August 2015):

> That warning has been there since well before 2003 (I couldn't be
>   bothered tracing the history back past a file rename in 2003).

And from Alexander Monakov on the same thread (referencing Bonzini's patch):

> A patch was proposed just recently to just remove the warning:
>   https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2015-08/msg00836.html

---

Related, Windows has `/ASLR`, which is address space layout randomization. Its optional, but often required as a security gate, meaning all program code on must be compiled with it. If you have an SDLC, then you are probably using `/ASLR` because Microsoft calls it out as a best practice in [Writing Secure Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735617228).

The Linux/Unix equivalent of `/ASLR` is `-fPIE` for executables.

Under Windows, all DLL code is relocatable. Under Linux/Unix, shared object code can be made relocatable with `-fPIC`.

`-fPIC` is a "superset" of `-fPIE` (some hand waiving). That means `-fPIC` can be used anywhere you would use `-fPIE` (but not vice-versa).

Answer (score 3):

> and how can I suppress it?

Not only a useless warning, but a distraction that makes it difficult to follow other warnings and errors.

Given my *make* output consistently showed 3 related lines, I opted to filter out the 3 "useless" lines using the following:

```
make 2>&1 | sed '/PIC ignored/{N;N;d;}'
```

I realize this is not the ideal way to suppress the noise, but maybe it will help to some degree. Be advised that I'm cutting 3 lines where other situations may only require removal of just one line. Note that I'm also routing stderr to stdout.

Here's a snipit of *make* output without the *sed*  filter:

```
libavcodec/x86/mlpdsp.c:51:36: warning: taking address of expression of type 'void'
                                    &ff_mlp_iirorder_4 };
                                    ^
CC      libavcodec/x86/motion_est_mmx.o
libavcodec/x86/motion_est_mmx.c:1:0: warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent)
 /* */ 
 ^
CC      libavcodec/x86/mpegaudiodec_mmx.o
libavcodec/x86/mpegaudiodec_mmx.c:1:0: warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent)
 /* */ 
 ^
CC      libavcodec/x86/mpegvideo_mmx.o
libavcodec/x86/mpegvideo_mmx.c:1:0: warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent)
 /* */ 
 ^
```

And the same with the *sed* filter:

```
                                                    ^
libavcodec/x86/mlpdsp.c:51:36: warning: taking address of expression of type 'void'
                                    &ff_mlp_iirorder_4 };
                                    ^
CC      libavcodec/x86/motion_est_mmx.o
CC      libavcodec/x86/mpegaudiodec_mmx.o
CC      libavcodec/x86/mpegvideo_mmx.o
CC      libavcodec/x86/proresdsp-init.o
```

Comment: The sed method worked for me.  Had the very same warnings for almost everything since we switched to using mingw

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I'd just add os detection to the makefile. Something along the lines of

```
TARGET_TRIPLE := $(subst -, ,$(shell $(CC) -dumpmachine))
TARGET_ARCH   := $(word 1,$(TARGET_TRIPLE))
TARGET_OS     := $(word 3,$(TARGET_TRIPLE))

ifeq      ($(TARGET_OS),mingw32)
else ifeq ($(TARGET_OS),cygwin)
else
CFLAGS += -fPIC
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

the switch has some effect on linux (on windows/cygwin it would do nothing, maybe the compiler did not add platform specific check heregg) code generated with -fPIC is position independent, that means all instructions that refer to a specific address must be replaced by redirection to memory location; memory location is then set by dynamic loader;  the result is is slightly slower - and takes more time to load; You don't need that for a static library, where all addresses are set by the linker, when the executable is created/linked.

The warning probably means that code of the static library is not quite as fast as you might expect it to be.You can create two object files of the same name in different directories, one with -fPIC for the shared library and the other for the static library.

Comment: you're mistaken; windows just does not support position-independent code in the unix sense; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code#Windows_DLLs