# Generated code not matching expectations with Extended ASM

Tags: c++, assembly, g++

I have a `CpuFeatures` class. The requirements for the class are simple: (1) preserve `EBX` or `RBX`, and (2) record the values returned from `CPUID` in `EAX/EBX/ECX/EDX`. I'm not sure the code being generated is the code I intended.

The `CpuFeatures` class code uses GCC Extended ASM. Here's the relevant code:

```
struct CPUIDinfo
{
    word32 EAX;
    word32 EBX;
    word32 ECX;
    word32 EDX;
};

bool CpuId(word32 func, word32 subfunc, CPUIDinfo& info)
{
    uintptr_t scratch;

    __asm__ __volatile__ (

        ".att_syntax \n"

#if defined(__x86_64__)
        "\t xchgq %%rbx, %q1 \n"
#else
        "\t xchgl %%ebx, %k1 \n"
#endif

        "\t cpuid \n"

#if defined(__x86_64__)
        "\t xchgq %%rbx, %q1 \n"
#else
        "\t xchgl %%ebx, %k1 \n"
#endif

      : "=a"(info.EAX), "=&r"(scratch), "=c"(info.ECX), "=d"(info.EDX)
      : "a"(func), "c"(subfunc)
    );

    if(func == 0)
        return !!info.EAX;

    return true;
}
```

The code below was compiled with `-g3 -Og` on Cygwin i386. When I examine it under a debugger, I'm don't like what I am seeing.

```
Dump of assembler code for function CpuFeatures::DoDetectX86Features():
   ...
   0x0048f355 <+1>:     sub    $0x48,%esp
=> 0x0048f358 <+4>:     mov    $0x0,%ecx
   0x0048f35d <+9>:     mov    %ecx,%eax
   0x0048f35f <+11>:    xchg   %ebx,%ebx
   0x0048f361 <+13>:    cpuid
   0x0048f363 <+15>:    xchg   %ebx,%ebx
   0x0048f365 <+17>:    mov    %eax,0x10(%esp)
   0x0048f369 <+21>:    mov    %ecx,0x18(%esp)
   0x0048f36d <+25>:    mov    %edx,0x1c(%esp)
   0x0048f371 <+29>:    mov    %ebx,0x14(%esp)
   0x0048f375 <+33>:    test   %eax,%eax
   ...
```

I don't like what I am seeing because it appears `EBX/RBX` is *not* being preserved (`xchg %ebx,%ebx` at `+11`). Additionally, it looks like the preserved `EBX/RBX` is being saved as the result of `CPUID`, and not the actual value of `EBX` returned by `CPUID` (`xchg %ebx,%ebx` at `+15`, before the `mov %ebx,0x14(%esp)` at `+29`).

If I change the operand to use a memory op with `"=&m"(scratch)`, then the generated code is:

```
0x0048f35e <+10>:    xchg   %ebx,0x40(%esp)
0x0048f362 <+14>:    cpuid
0x0048f364 <+16>:    xchg   %ebx,0x40(%esp)
```

A related question is [What ensures reads/writes of operands occurs at desired times with extended ASM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32099922)

What am I doing wrong (besides wasting countless hours on something that should have taken 5 or 15 minutes)?

Comment: You may have missed a comment I made on the last question we discussed. You might consider using a specific register like `"=D"` instead of `=&r` . However regarding the reuse of `%ebx` - this is only an issue IF `%ebx` _needs_ to be preserved. I noticed you didn't compile with `-fPIC` which suggests to me that the compiler is free to use `ebx`. What happens if you compile with `-fPIC` ?

Comment: My guess is with `-fPIC` it shouldn't use `ebx` and will probably pick `%esi` (or another available register) next.

Comment: Should also point out that when producing x86_64 even with `-fPIC` it may not be an issue because usage of PIC code also depends on the memory model used (and the ABI). `%rbx` may not need to be preserved (PIC is handled differently in those cases). This [article](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/11/position-independent-code-pic-in-shared-libraries-on-x64) a reasonable explanation of PIC on X86_64

Comment: @MichaelPetch - Compiling with `-fPIC` on Cygwin results in [-fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent), useless warning](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16708148) and [Why does Cygwin's GCC display the first line of every file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31149950).

Comment: @MichaelPetch - *"...x86_64 even with -fPIC it may not be an issue"* - that's the issue. It may (or may not) be needed. For us, its easier to save it in all cases to avoid any questions and future (or past) problems. For us, the past dates back to the 1990s, so we need to ensure we are not breaking down level (ancient) clients.

Comment: I don't use Cygwin, and if they don't support `-fPIC` then there is no issue since the compiler knows `%ebx`doesn't need to be preserved. So as it stands I would say the generated code you showed is fine since `%ebx` is in fact a free register under those conditions.

Comment: If you are concerned about ancient compilers and handling of `-fPIC` consider replacing `=&r` with `=D`. That will force the use of the `%esi`/`%rsi` register and avoid the use of `%ebx`/`%rbx` altogether.

Comment: I don't have a 2.9x compiler handy, but it would have been a serious bug had the assembler templates not handled the `ebx` scenario properly with `-fPIC`.

Comment: I see you amended your question to show usage of `=&m`. That output looks good, however using `=D` wouldn't require the memory addressing penalty.

Comment: @Michael - the updated code shows that the swap of `EBX` occurs to memory, but it still occurs too soon. `0x40(%esp)` is `scratch`.

Comment: Not enough instructions to tell if it is a problem. I'd expect to find that in the instructions below what you actually presented (using `=&m`) that the contents of `0x40(%esp)` are likely accessed later to get the value that was in `%ebx` . `ebx` doesn't contain the value we want to use (it has been obliterated when the original value was restored). What was transferred to memory(stack in this case) should have the correct value and should eventually appear later in the code when the value is needed.

Comment: In your case you don't seem to use `scratch` at all after it is returned from the assembler template so you won't find any code using it. See what code is generated if you add this line after the assembler template. `info.EBX = scratch` . With code like this you should find that eventually `0x40(%esp)` is moved to the memory where `info.EBX` is stored.

Comment: I think you missed something when you updated your code to use `scratch`. I think you meant to use `"=&m"(scratch)` and not `"=&r"(scratch)` Technically speaking you should be able to use `"=&m"(info.EBX)` which should swap (swap = `xchgl %%ebx, %k1`)  `%ebx` right into the `info` structure rather than use the `scratch` variable at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below is a complete example that I used to compile your example code above including the modification to exchange(swap) directly to the `info.EBX` variable.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#define word32 uint32_t

struct CPUIDinfo
{
    word32 EAX;
    word32 EBX;
    word32 ECX;
    word32 EDX;
};

bool CpuId(word32 func, word32 subfunc, CPUIDinfo& info)
{
    __asm__ __volatile__ (

        ".att_syntax \n"

#if defined(__x86_64__)
        "\t xchgq %%rbx, %q1 \n"
#else
        "\t xchgl %%ebx, %k1 \n"
#endif

        "\t cpuid \n"

#if defined(__x86_64__)
        "\t xchgq %%rbx, %q1 \n"
#else
        "\t xchgl %%ebx, %k1 \n"
#endif

      : "=a"(info.EAX), "=&m"(info.EBX), "=c"(info.ECX), "=d"(info.EDX)
      : "a"(func), "c"(subfunc)
    );

    if(func == 0)
        return !!info.EAX;

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    CPUIDinfo  cpuInfo;
    CpuId(1, 0, cpuInfo);
}
```

The first observation that you should make is that I chose to use the info.EBX memory location to do the actual swap to. This eliminates needing a another temporary variable or register.

I assembled as 32-bit code with `-g3 -Og -S -m32` and got these instructions of interest:

```
xchgl %ebx, 4(%edi)
cpuid
xchgl %ebx, 4(%edi)

movl    %eax, (%edi)
movl    %ecx, 8(%edi)
movl    %edx, 12(%edi)
```

`%edi` happens to contain the address of the `info` structure. `4(%edi)` happens to be the address of `info.EBX`. We swap `%ebx` and `4(%edi)` after `cpuid`. With that instruction `ebx` is restored to what it was before `cpuid` and `4(%edi)` now has what `ebx` was right after `cpuid` was executed. The remaining `movl` lines place `eax`, `ecx`, `edx` registers into the rest of the `info` structure via the `%edi` register.

The generated code above is what I would expect it to be.

Your code with the `scratch` variable (and using the constraint `"=&m"(scratch)`) never gets used after the assembler template so `%ebx,0x40(%esp)` has the value you want but it never gets moved anywhere useful. You'd have to copy the `scratch` variable into `info.EBX` (ie. `info.EBX = scratch;`)and look at all of the resulting instructions that get generated. At some point the data would be copied from the `scratch` memory location to `info.EBX` among the generated assembly instructions.

**Update - Cygwin and MinGW**

I wasn't entirely satisfied that the Cygwin code output was correct. In the middle of the night I had an Aha! moment. Windows already does its own position independent code when the dynamic link loader loads an image (DLL etc) and modifies the image via re-basing. There is no need for additional PIC processing like it is done in Linux 32 bit shared libraries so there is no issue with `ebx`/`rbx`. This is why Cygwin and MinGW will present warnings like this when compiling with `-fPIC`

> warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent)

This is because under Windows all 32bit code can be re-based when it is loaded by the Windows dynamic loader. More about re-basing can be found in this [Dr. Dobbs article](http://www.drdobbs.com/rebasing-win32-dlls/184416272). Information on the windows Portable Executable format (PE) can be found in this [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable). Cygwin and MinGW don't need to worry about preserving `ebx`/`rbx` when targeting 32bit code because on their platforms PIC is already handled by the OS, other re-basing tools, and the linker.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I no longer trust this extended ASM, so I'm abandoning it. It may (or may not) be producing correct code; but its clearly not reasonably auditable. Since we can't easily verify it, there's no sense in using it.

Comment: No problem. I've been using assembler templates for years and haven't had issues. `cpuid` caught my attention because I actually use `cpuid` in [GNU Backgammon](http://www.gnubg.org) via assembler templates. Among other things you also have to be careful because not all i386 processors support `cpuid` so you really need to check that the processor supports `cpuid`. That check is done by looking for a side effect of `pushfl` and a `popl` (have to love Intel lol)

Comment: cool, I did not know you were a maintainer. Related, I have a few Apple machines if you are interested in supporting it. I use the GNU Test Farm too, and I know it does not have them. My setup includes a G5 (PowerPC, OS X 10.5), a MackBook (Intel, OS X 10.9), and a MacBook Pro (Intel, OS X 10.8; ancient C++ standard library that claims to be C++11).

Comment: Already support OS/X as well (We are also in macports). I still retain my own G5 from over a decade ago just so I can do builds for that platform. I have a couple mac minis as well. Seems like you and I keep Apple equipment for similar reasons - testing our software!

Comment: Here's the next question in the saga: [Assembler templates, asmSymbolicName and “error: expected string-literal”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32131950). Like I said earlier, the code and its verification should have taken all of about 15 minutes. Its amazing it has managed to drag out for days.

Comment: I have added an important addition the the bottom of my answer to address the PIC code generation  with Cygwin and MinGW that you may wish to read. IMHO, Cygwin got it right for a target platform of i386 and Win32.

Comment: Oh, cool. For us, its simple: always save `EBX/RBX` and there are never any questions. We can spare 6 CPU cycles for peace of mind.

Comment: By the way, have you tested on Cygwin/i386 with `-Og`. I get sporadic crashes at different points. Usually `std::string::reserve` is somewhere in the call stack (that includes `cygwin.dll`. But when I try to get a good backtrace, too much of the frame appears corrupt, so I can't get info on the locals.

Comment: No, I only have MinGW/MSYS2 installed. Do those crashes occur without the cpuid functionality?

Comment: I recently came across Debian's [X32 port](https://wiki.debian.org/X32Port). Its an interesting platform because you use 32-bit integers, longs and pointers and ASM; but you interact with the stack using 64-bit registers.