# Assembler templates, asmSymbolicName and "error: expected string-literal"

Tags: gcc, assembly

I'm trying to use GCC's extended ASM like Microsoft's assembler. Under Microsoft's MASM, we can do the following, where `__FUNC` is a C variable:

```
mov eax, __FUNC
```

According to [Extended Asm - Assembler Instructions with C Expression Operands](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html), § 6.44.3.1 *Input Operands*:

> Operands are separated by commas. Each operand has this format:
>
> ```
>  [ [asmSymbolicName] ] constraint (cexpression)
> ```
>
> asmSymbolicName
>
> Specifies a symbolic name for the operand. Reference the name in the assembler template by enclosing it in square brackets (i.e. ‘%[Value]’). The scope of the name is the asm statement that contains the definition. Any valid C variable name is acceptable, including names already defined in the surrounding code...

When I try and use it in code:

```
unsigned int func = 1;
...

__asm__ __volatile__ (
  "movl %[__FUNC], %%eax"
  ...

  :
  : __FUNC "" (func)
);
```

It results in:

```
cpu.cpp:148:5: error: expected string-literal before ‘__FUNC’
 : __FUNC "" (func)
   ^
cpu.cpp:148:5: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘__FUNC’
cpu.cpp:148:17: error: ‘__FUNC’ was not declared in this scope
...
```

The best I can tell, I am using `__FUNC` according to the manual and its description of `asmSymbolicName`. But obviously I am not since there's an error.

What am I doing wrong?

---

I also tried the following because the manual told me I could use variable names in surrounding code, but it did not work either:

```
"movl %[func], %%eax"
...

:
: func "" (func)
```

And:

```
"movl %[func], %%eax"
...

:
: func (func)
...
```

Comment: Also see [GCC Bug 67301 - Unable to compile program using extended assembly and asmSymbolicName](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67301). Since no one pointed out obvious mistakes in the use of asmSymbolicName, I'm going to write it off as a compiler-driver or documentation bug.

Comment: I'd say more of a documentation issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct:

> Operands are separated by commas. Each operand has this format:
>
> ```
> [  [asmSymbolicName]  ] constraint (cexpression)
> ```

However `[asmSymbolicName]` means `asmSymbolicName` is literally surrounded by square brackets `[` and `]` (The outside brackets say that it is an optional parameter). You might have been going for this:

```
uint32_t func = 1;
uint32_t result;

__asm__ __volatile__ (
    "movl %[func], %[result]"
    : [result]"=a"(result)
    : [func]"g"(func)
);
```

This takes an input parameter of `func` makes it available as a symbolic name called `func` within the assembler template. Output parameter is `eax` (writable) with a symbolic name of `result` and `eax` will be stored in the C variable `result` when finished. I chose "g" since any immediate value, memory address, or register would be appropriate for the source in `movl` . You could pass an immediate value rather than a "C" variable with:

```
: [func]"g"(42)
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. Hopefully the GCC folks will improve the docs surrounding that.

Comment: Related, if I am only using operands to map `asmSymbolicName` to `cexpression` (for a quasi-MASM style of inline assembly), then does it matter whether they show up in Input or Output operands? What I found is, if I follow convention of input and output operands, then I have to use `"="` in the output constraint, which may duplicate the code I am providing.

Comment: According to the GCC [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) all output constraints need to have an equal modifier,

Comment: According to the documentation for assembly templates you do not want to write to input operands (unless an output operand is also tied to it). The docs have this to say: "_Do not modify the contents of input-only operands (except for inputs tied to outputs). The compiler assumes that on exit from the asm statement these operands contain the same values as they had before executing the statement_"